# Why do I get 'Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule'?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a angular app that works but not in codesandbox. This is the error I am getting:

> Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule
>   evaluate main.ts:11:25    8 |   enableProdMode();    9 | }   10 |
>
> > 11 | platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
> >          |                         ^   12 |   .catch(err => console.error(err));   13 |

[Link to code](https://m4qv1wq5vx.codesandbox.io/)

Comment: I think it is an issue with codesandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be codesandbox did not support angular 7.

I tried to forked your app and update package.json to angular 5 (default of codesandbox) and it worked.

You can recheck your issue in package.json file.

https://codesandbox.io/s/62pyvx8jjr